# Correct way to make PDO Connection for classes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

Is this a correct way to make PDO Connection.

I have different classes (each class have its own file) then there is config file contain PDO object and all classes objects. I am doing it correctly or there is any better practice.

classA.php

```
class classA {

    private $PDO;

    function __construct($PDO) { 
        $this->PDO = $PDO;
    }
    //other functions
}
```

classB.php

```
class classB {

    private $PDO;

    function __construct($PDO) { 
        $this->PDO = $PDO;
    }
    //other functions
}
```

classC.php

```
class classC {

    private $PDO;

    function __construct($PDO) { 
        $this->PDO = $PDO;
    }
    //other functions
}
```

And in config.php page:

```
include_once("db.php"); //contains db variables values
try
{
    $PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to connect database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

require 'classA.php';
require 'classB.php';
require 'classC.php';

$objA = new classA($PDO);
$objB = new classB($PDO);
$objC = new classC($PDO);
```

include config.php on almost every page.

Comment: That's perfect and clean code. Go ahead with it :-).

Comment: I recommend reading answers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047264/use-of-pdo-in-classes

Comment: Thanks @rus13th, so you are suggesting "core" class practice is better approach then above I am using?

Comment: Sorry, it is opinion based question.

Comment: also ... I get a feeling that your problem has less to do with "correct approach to making PDO connection" as it is with learning about autoloader and concept of bootstrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Short: yes, it's correct, but not perfect.

I think that you are doing it right. It's called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

But your code has duplicates([DRY!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). You could avoid it with using inheritance.

Also. Do not catch exceptions at all if you want just to "die".

> include config.php on almost every page.

It would be better if you would do [central point of entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604046/having-a-single-entry-point-to-a-website-bad-good-non-issue). [Front contoller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me how I can avoid `include_once("config.php")` for pages and have access to classes. Can you please tell me which code is duplicating and any hint to fix it. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Your application should has one point of entry: index.php. [Read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)

Comment: Thanks I'll study it further.

Comment: So PDO connecting method is perfect ? unless change the app structure to  Front contoller pattern ? Or I can do it any better way.

Comment: @fmask, one class classA is perfect. But together they ruin DRY principle.

Comment: Also you could use lazy PDO realization.

Comment: Right now your code is not perfect. But i cannot say when it would be perfect: it's option based and it depends on your issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. so accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047264/use-of-pdo-in-classes is good approach according to my situation? or it also come in to DRY! domain.

Comment: Actually no. There is one issue: [singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons)

Comment: Great so Dependency Injection is better than Singleton and I can use current connection method while I move app to Front controller pattern.

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation your approach is fine. ( Not Front controller pattern)

Avoid singleton as Dependency Injection is clean and maintainable.

Even Erich Gamma, one of the Singleton pattern's inventors, doubts this pattern nowadays:

["I'm in favor of dropping Singleton. Its use is almost always a design smell"](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1404056)